# Get all connected peer(Peer.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, p2p, peerjs

How can i get all connected peers if i have simple server:

```
    var port = 9000;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send('server OK');
    //console.log(ip.address());
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use('/peerjs',ExpressPeerServer(server));

server.listen(port,'0.0.0.0');
```

and client:

```
var peer = new Peer(
        {host:"hostname",
         port:9000,path:"/peerjs",
         debug:3,
         config:servers, 
         });
```

i use peerjs lib. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peer.js has method `listAllPeers`  on the client side. And you can use it if you add `allow_discovery: true` parameter in options on the server side.

[This should help you](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/173#issuecomment-146438773)